# Как отловить с какой стороны ты расширяешь окно в ширину в WindowsForms

Tags: c#

При расширении с левой стороны влево идёт сдвиг элементов графики вправо, но и при расширении с правой стороны вправо идёт сдвиг элементов графики вправо (а мне нужно влево). И я не знаю как их отловить

```
protected override void OnResize(System.EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnResize(e);
                if (iWidth > 0)
                {
                    xEllipce++; xLine++; x1Line++;
                }
                else
                {
                    xEllipce--; xLine--; x1Line--;
                }
                tree.VisualiseTree(g, xEllipce, yEllipce, xLine, yLine, x1Line, y1Line);
            }
```

Comment: Сначала сами поймите для себя то, что пытаетесь запрограммировать. Что значит "расширение влево", а что значит "расширение вправо"? Подсказка: когда окно "расширяется влево", сдвигается его левый угол, а правый остаётся неподвижным. И наоборот.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Да, это то, что мне надо. Как отловить сдвиг левого угла?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private int oldLeft, oldRight;
protected override void OnResize(System.EventArgs e) {
  base.OnResize(e);
  bool isChanged = false;
  if (oldLeft > this.Left) {
    xEllipce += 2; xLine += 2; x1Line += 2;
    isChanged = true;
  }
  else if (oldRight < this.Right) {
    xEllipce -= 2; xLine -= 2; x1Line -= 2;
    isChanged = true;
  }
  if (isChanged) tree.VisualiseTree(g, xEllipce, yEllipce, xLine, yLine, x1Line, y1Line);
    oldLeft = this.Left;
    oldRight = this.Right; 

}
```